# What kind of work experience should be included in a math CV for PhD programs?

Tags: career, advice

I am applying to numerous PhD programs in number theory for admission next fall and I want to have a CV prepared, in part because I want to attach a CV to emails I send out to professors at some of my target schools. I am currently taking a gap year between undergrad and grad school by working as a web developer at a large, well-known tech company. My work is not particularly relevant to number theory (sure, crypto comes up every now and then, but it's certainly not on an abstract mathematical basis). Do I include this work experience anywhere in my CV, or leave it out completely? I don't have much relevant work experience (I have participated in paid mathematical research through my undergrad institution, but I feel that these experiences should be placed under "research experience" rather than "work experience").

(Edit: for those wondering, I am taking this gap year to completely pay off my undergrad loans and maintain a savings account that will provide extra support during grad school)

Comment: My 'gap year' was five years long. An important thing is to have good recommendation letters from school. (If you can, do some study/research prep on the side.)  Also, this question fits better at Academia StackExchange.  Gerhard "Having Good Work Experience Helps" Paseman, 2019.08.29.

Comment: Yes, you do. Computer programming skill is a valuable asset in mathematics research.

Answer (score 5):

I answer questions like this all the time from undergraduates at the university where I teach. In general, **yes, you should include work experience in technical fields.** This work experience shows those reading your file several things about you:

1. You are able to hold a job. You know how to show up on time and work well with others.
2. You are a self-starter, choosing to go to grad school because you really want to, rather than drifting aimlessly and going to grad school because some undergrad advisor suggested it.
3. You have the ability to teach yourself technical skills and carry out what you learned at a high level. This is HUGE for success at research.
4. The kinds of things you thought about in industry might inform your future math research. Even if you get a PhD in number theory, perhaps someday you'll be doing math research that underlies the considerations of web developers. For example, perhaps you learn some nifty thing in grad school and realize it can be applied to modeling internet traffic on the web graph. We as a community of mathematicians get better math when we let in folks whose lived experience helps them create better mathematical models for reality.

Not super relevant as you apply for a PhD, but:

5. When applying for a professorship, prior industry experience is also a strength, because, in addition to the reasons listed above, it makes you a stronger advisor. Most undergraduates will not go on to become professors. Most professors never worked outside of academia. A professor who has can give very useful advice to students. Furthermore, perhaps your skills could help the university in some way, e.g., by consulting for the University Communications department (who runs the uni webpage). After all, service is part of the job of a professor.

Lastly, there are many good threads about this kind of question over on academia.SE:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/planning-for-grad-school

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202481/how-do-us-math-phd-admissions-committees-view-students-who-come-from-industry

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62178/is-a-short-cv-problematic

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59607/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-say-in-my-statement-of-purpose-that-i-want-to-pursue-a-phd-i

Comment: I’m very skeptical that non-academic employment will help someone applying for jobs in academia.  I’m not saying it will hurt you, just that it is kind of irrelevant and people will basically ignore it.

Comment: @AndyPutman For liberal arts jobs, I've heard from multiple sources that it can help, for the reason I said related to advising. I, too, worked briefly outside academia and was told that this helped me get my job. But, it's more of a "cherry on top" and doesn't compensate for a lack of the other pieces of getting a tenure track job.